# There is a problem when I run Levenstein code

Tags: c++, constants, levenshtein-distance

While programming Levenstein, there is a problem. It is an extracted code from the Internet.

The code as follows:

```cpp
#define MIN3(a, b, c) ((a) < (b) ? ((a) < (c) ? (a) : (c)) : ((b) < (c) ? (b) : (c)))

int levenshtein(char *s1, char *s2) {
    unsigned int s1len, s2len, x, y, lastdiag, olddiag;
    s1len = strlen(s1);
    s2len = strlen(s2);
    unsigned int column[s1len + 1];
    for (y = 1; y <= s1len; y++)
        column[y] = y;
    for (x = 1; x <= s2len; x++) {
        column[0] = x;
        for (y = 1, lastdiag = x - 1; y <= s1len; y++) {
            olddiag = column[y];
            column[y] = MIN3(column[y] + 1, column[y - 1] + 1, lastdiag + (s1[y - 1] == s2[x - 1] ? 0 : 1));
            lastdiag = olddiag;
        }
    }
    return(column[s1len]);
}
```

The problem lies in the statement: `unsigned int column[s1len + 1];` on `unsigned int s1len`:

> Error: Expression must have a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that the `C++` language **does not support** variable-length arrays (VLAs). The code you've gleaned from the internet was possibly/probably written as `C`, which is a **different language** from `C++` and *does* support VLAs (since the C99 standard, IIRC).

You can 'fix' your code to work with *standard* `C++` by using the `std::vector` container, in place of the VLA. Be sure to include the `<vector>` header file:

```cpp
#include <vector>
//.. .
// unsigned int column[s1len + 1];  // NOT standard C++
   std::vector<unsigned int>column(s1len + 1);
```

You can access the elements of the vector using its `[]` operator, so you don't need any other changes in your code.

Note: Some `C++` implementations *do* support VLAs (I think GNU g++ is one that does) - but the standard doesn't.